# Using a webservice in Delphi by manually building XML (i.e. bypassing WSDL)

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi, xml-parsing, wsdl

I am pretty clear on how to use web-services in Delphi using the built-in WSDL importer and then calling webservice components (almost) as if they were "regular" delphi methods and variables.

The problem is that I want to access a set of webservices (both put and get--i.e. "read" and "write"--operations) without having to access it through WSDL generated constructs. Long story on why I don't want to use the WSDL generated constructs in this case.

In a nutshell, this is what I would like to accomplish:

1. General XML manually (i.e. using something like TXMLDocument, etc) which would be sent over http to the webserver to invoke a webservice.
2. Read back the response from the server and parse the XML to find out what the response was.

I have experimented with this:
- generate a webservice call using the webservice construct built into Delphi (i.e. WSDL importer and all).
- using events, replace the outgoing XML packet with my own.
- upon response from web service, repeat the process. That is, inspect the packet using events, and read the XML coming back from server and parse it myself.

In theory, it shall work but it appears very ameteurish and kludgy to me. I would like to do it so that I am in control of the whole process and the code is generating calls and reading responses using propoer net controls built into Delphi. Any tips on what is the best way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. I am using Delphi XE5 update 2.

Comment: I would use SOAPUI to inspect/craft the SOAP Envelopes. Using TXMLDocument and TIdHTTP will accomplish what you want...

Comment: Yes, I am using SOAPUI to inspect SOAP envelopes to gain an insight into what the XML payload should/would look like. Is using TidHTTP for calling web services as simple as sumbmitting a "regular" http request and then waiting for a response? Thanks.

Comment: Yes indeed, calling a webservice is nothing more than an ordinary http request. There are problems when you interact with WCF services (authentication and that sort of stuff). For normal vanilla webservices, this approach will work...

Comment: I am doing the exact same stuff handling SOAP communication with Exchange Webservices - because the WDSL import did not work. You have to build it from the ground up and it's a lot of work. So it's doable but your question is too broad.

Comment: Jan, would you please expand on "its a lot of work"? Are you referring to building the XML and then parsing the response, or the details invovled in http communication, or ? Thanks.